# Session to transfer value

Tags: jsp, session

I have use session to transfer value from one jsp page to other one by creating session and getting it on other jsp page but on other page it print null So I am not receiving value .

```
//set the session
 <% try{
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","ankit","ankit27");
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    String a=request.getParameter("t1");
                    String b=request.getParameter("p1");
                    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select REASON from LEAVE");
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        String un=rs.getString(1);

                        %><div name="div1"  value="<%=""+un %>" > <%=""+un %></div>
                            <%String n=request.getParameter("div1");
                        session.setAttribute("name1",n); %>
                    <% }
                    else{
                        out.println("no user");
                    }

            } 
                catch(Exception e){
                    out.println(e);
                }

                %>

//get the session
       <div ><%=(String)session.getAttribute("name1") %> </div>
```

Comment: Elaborate on your question. It's not clear what you need.

Comment: I want to use value from one page to print on other page by using session